# How to pass arguments between scripts and functions

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am making a kivy app and I have been looking for a way to pass variables from one script (script 1) to another (script 2). Once the variables are now in script 2, i want to pass them from one function to another, where the variables will then be added to a listview in my kivy app. The data being sent from Script 1.py was from Script 1.kv.

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eI6O.png)

Or is there an easier way to send input data from Script1.kv to Script2.py
Thank you in advance

Comment: I mean, there are a lot of ways to do things. It is your code, so you can define how methods are defined.  That being said, you might have some luck passing in maps, OR for better definition, you could use things like **kwargs, which will allow a function to maintain its parameters, and essentially take maps and explode them to their correct spots in the function as long as arg names match etc

Comment: After looking at your script though, why not create a screen object in however you see fit, and then have a parser in both of those classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you using **Screen**s you may use a global *ScreenManager* to get reference to them

```
from script2 import Results

class Sender(Screen):
    ...
    def send(self):
        r = sm.get_screen('results')
        r.get(start, end price)
sm = None

class YourApp(App):
    def build(self):
        global sm
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Results(name='results'))
        sm.add_widget(Sender(name='sender'))
        return sm
```